# How do I fix this error: Exception thrown at 0x00E33743 in Project235.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: visual-studio-2015, x86

I have an error thrown at 0x00E33743 in Visual Studios 2015 and I am currently working with x86 Assembly Language. My goal is for this procedure to copy bytes from a supplied input BYTE array to a target BYTE array. The problem is that when I get down to mov eax,[esi] that loads the value of the target in eax, that is when the error is thrown. I was wondering if anyone knew why I am receiving that error and could help me.

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; copies bytes from a supplied input BYTE array to a target BYTE array
; receives:         
;   [ebp-4] = pointer to buffer array
;   [ebp-8] = pointer to the output byte array
;   [ebp-12] = max size buffer
; returns:
;   eax = the pointer to the next character in the input array after the carriage return and line feed characters
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bufferCopy PROC
    push ebp                                        ; save the base pointer
    mov ebp,esp                                     ; base of the stack frame
    push OFFSET buffer                              ; points to the beginning of buffer
    push OFFSET olympian                            ; pointer to the output array
    push BSIZE                                      ; buffer size
    sub esp,16                                      ; create temp variable "tmp"
    push esi                                        ; save esi
    push eax                                        ; save eax

; store the input byte into the max size
    mov esi,[ebp-4]                                 ; load pointer to byte in esi
    mov ecx,[ebp-12]                                ; max size of the buffer
    mov eax,[esi]                                   ; load the value of byte in eax
    mov [ebp-16],eax                                ; store in tmp

; move target byte to the input byte
    mov esi,[ebp-8]                                 ; load pointer to target in esi
    mov eax,[esi]                                   ; load the value of target in eax
    mov esi,[ebp-4]                                 ; load pointer to input byte in esi
    mov [esi],eax                                   ; move eax (target) to input location

; move tmp/input to target
    mov eax,[ebp-16]                                ; move value stored in max (input) to eax
    mov esi,[ebp-8]                                 ; load pointer to target in esi
    mov [esi],eax                                   ; move eax (input) to target location
    push [esi]+1                                    ; moving the target's pointer over

    push [esi]+2                                    ; moving the target's pointer over
    pop eax                                         ; restore eax
    pop esi                                         ; restore esi
    pop ebp                                         ; remove base pointer

    ret                                             ; clean up stack!
bufferCopy ENDP
```

Comment: Which instruction faulted?  Use the debugger to see, and to look at registers.

Comment: Just a couple of things: 1/ It's rather unusual for a function to push its *own* parameters on the stack, that's usually done by the caller and you'd get at them with `[bp+something]`. 2/ Short of a `byte ptr` somewhere, `mov eax,[esi]` should load a 32-bit value, *not* a byte as your comments seem to indicate. In any case, as @Peter states, you should learn to use a debugger - it's much faster than theorising about where the problem lies :-)

Comment: Just looked at this again: `mov [esi], eax` and then two pushes of `[esi]+1` and `+2` are *very* suspicious.  You pop right away, so what you're really doing is `mov eax, [esi+1]` / `mov esi, [esi+2]` (unaligned loads that partially overlap the earlier store).  Note that `[esi]+1` in Microsoft syntax is the same as `[esi+1]`.  It doesn't add 1 to the value loaded.

Comment: If you want to load a byte, use `movzx eax,byte ptr [esi]` etc...or, if the rest of EAX is unimportant and only the low 8 bits count, use `mov al,[esi]`. EAX is a 32 bit register, so you are loading 4 bytes from the address, unless you do what I wrote above. The same for writing.